# How can I convert my Set to an array efficiently?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, set

So I am trying to generate an array that is filled with unique randomized integers and I found out that doing this with an arraylist would be the most efficient way to do so.

```
public static int [] randArr(int n, int max){
       randArr = new int[n];
       Random rn = new Random();
       Set<Integer> test = new HashSet<Integer>();
       
      while(test.size() < n){
      test.add(rn.nextInt(0, max));
 
        }
}
```

Now I tried working with `randArr = test.toArray()` but I am not quite sure, what to put in the parentheses nor if this really can work. Is there any other method for converting, since I cannot simply assign randArr with the integers of test through `test.get(i)` with a for-loop either.

Comment: [`Collection::toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T%5B%5D))?

Comment: @Turing85 That will not work to create an `int[]` array.

Comment: Hmm... true... sometimes, I hate primitives

Comment: You can use `int[] arr = set.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();` to convert given `set` is a variable of type `Set<Integer>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a set. `Stream` the random numbers, remove dups using `distinct`, and limit using `limit`

```
public static int [] randArr(int n, int max){
    Random rn = new Random();
    return rn.ints(0,max).distinct().limit(n).toArray(); 
}
```

**Notes:**

- Make certain that `n is <= max`, otherwise you could be waiting a while.
- `max must be >= 1` (required by `Random.ints` method)

You may want to put in some code to enforce those `invariants` and throw an appropriate exception if not in compliance. Something like the following (or whatever makes sense to you).

```
if (n > max || max <= 0) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "n(%d) <= max(%d) or max > 0 not in compliance"
                .formatted(n,max));
}
```